# FBSDKShareLinkContent without deep linking to app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm using `FBSDKShareLinkContent` to display a dialog to share a link to Facebook.  No matter the link I use (I even tried with https://google.com/) when the post / link is tapped in the Facebook app my app is launched.

I want, however, to load the link in a web browser or the FB browser instead (and not have it launch my app or navigate to the app store).  Is there anyway to achieve this?  I tried both `FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb` and `FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic`.

Here is my current code:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://google.com/"];

FBSDKShareDialog* dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedWeb;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.fromViewController = self;
[dialog show];
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that you are tapping the app attribution link or something like that?

Comment: Is the issue resolved yet?

Comment: is self and a controller of stack of controllers based navigationViewController ?

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your code:**

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content1 = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content1.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"];
content1.contentTitle=@"Share";
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content1 delegate:nil];
```